# Remove Invalid Parenthesis

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Remove the invalid parenthesis using Python in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space. I have few approaches which will take O(n log n) and O(n^2) time and also O(n) both space and time. But, I am looking for one which minimal time. I tried searching in web but couldn't found any approach to solve.

For example:

```
input - {}{}{{}}}}}{{{{{}
output - {}{}{{}}{}
```

There are several other edge cases too.

Comment: Have you tried two pointers approach?

Comment: I havent Can you explain a bit more

Comment: Check for invalid parenthesis from the left side, if the counter value is less than 0, then it is invalid one -- ignore this parenthesis to make it valid. Repeat this from the right side too for left invalid parenthesis.

Comment: sounds good i will give it a shot

Comment: Can you please explain the problem in a formal way. How do you know which parenthesis must be removed ?

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, the nesting levels are as follows:

```
 { } { } { { } } } } } { { { { { }
 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0-1-2-3-2-1 0 1 2 1
```

If you discard the negative ones (on the fly),

```
 { } { } { { } } { { { { { }
 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4
```

Now repeat from the right.

```
 { } { } { { } } { { { { { }
-2-3-2-3-4-3-2-3-4-3-2-1 0 1
```

and

```
 { } { } { { } } { }
 0 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 0 1
```